# Maintain div equal height in each tab navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, height

[image]

[image]

I want to maintain the div height based on the content in each tab navigation. 
Right now I used this Code to maintain the div height

```
$.fn.equalHeights = function () {
var max_height = 0;
$(this).each(function () {
    max_height = Math.max($(this).height(), max_height);
});
$(this).each(function () {
    $(this).height(max_height);
});
};

$('.card-content').equalHeights();
```

But here am facing the issue like, whenever the page loads Tab 1 Div only working fine, remaining the tab nav tabs div content it doesn't work.

Even I tried to change the class name for each tab's div. how can I maintain the div equal height based on the tabs content?

Comment: Post your html.

Comment: post html......

Comment: Please check out my answer and accept it if it works with you

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using CSS only. `col-container` is the parenting `div` for `div.card-content` or `.col` in this example.

```
.col-container {
     display: table; /* Make the container element behave like a table */
     width: 100%; /* Set full-width to expand the whole page */
}

.col {
     display: table-cell; /* Make elements inside the container behave like table cells */
}
```